# Sending a file from a device to a computer does not work (File gets broken)

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using this code to sent a file from my pc to a other pc.

The reciever:

```
    String filename = "";
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    BufferedReader br;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while(true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            filename = din.readUTF();

            String[] splitname = filename.split(Pattern.quote("/"));
            String realfile = splitname[splitname.length -1];

            long sz = Long.parseLong(din.readUTF());

            BufferedInputStream get = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            //Speicherort (Config?)
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Send/Empfangen/" + realfile),true);


            long u;
            byte bb[]= new byte [1024];
            long bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = din.read(bb, 0, bb.length);
                fos.write(bb,0,bb.length);

            }while(!(bytesRead<1024));
            fos.close();
            dout.close();
            socket.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

The sender:

```
    Socket soc;
    DataOutputStream dc;
    PrintWriter pw;
    String msg = "";
    try{
        msg = "test.png";

        soc = new Socket("IP", 5000);

        dc = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());

        //Filename
        dc.writeUTF(msg);
        dc.flush();

        File fi = new File(msg);

        long size = (int) fi.length();

        //Size of file
        dc.writeUTF(Long.toString(size));
        dc.flush();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fi);
        OutputStream out = soc.getOutputStream();

        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        soc.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I use it like this, I can send any file from my laptop to my desktop pc.
But when I copy this code into my app and send a file from my device,
it gets broken. PDFs are only have half of the text, images only a quarter of its look.

For example a profile picture:
[image]

This is what it looks on my phone.
After the I sended it to my computer it looked like this:
[image]

So its now totaly broken.

Why does it work from pc to pc, but not from android to pc?
Is there any way to get this working?

Thanks for answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

one thing that is wrong with your server code logic is that you assumed InputStream.(byte[], int, int) will always read as many bytes as you specified in the third parameter, it doesn't ([read here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int))).

change this part:

```
        long bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = din.read(bb, 0, bb.length);
            fos.write(bb,0,bb.length);

        }while(!(bytesRead<1024));
```

to this

```
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead=din.read(bb))>-1){
            fos.write(bb,0,bytesRead);
        }
```